# mySQL join with where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my db and it is one to many connection with other as shown below

[image]

In kvves_units table I will get '`name`' from the `GET` Method

now I want to have all value from the `kvves_units` and `kvves_members` according to the name of the `kvves_units`

I'm using the code something like this

```
$kvvesDetails = $conn->prepare( "SELECT u.id, u.name, u.phone, u.email, u.address, m.name,    m.designantion, m.phone, m.email, m.imageFROM kvves_units AS u JOIN kvves_members AS m ON m.unit_id = u.id WHERE `name` = $committee");
```

Comment: That is a standard join. Didn't you take at least a SQL tutorial or what is the special problem with this case?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What does your current query look like?

Comment: look for LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN ... mysql.com will be your friend

Comment: $kvvesDetails = $conn->prepare(
                            "SELECT u.id, u.name, u.phone, u.email, u.address, m.name, m.designantion, m.phone, m.email, m.image
                            FROM kvves_units AS u
                            JOIN kvves_members AS m ON m.unit_id = u.id WHERE `name` = $committee"
                            );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard join:

```
$kvvesDetails = $conn->prepare( "SELECT u.id, u.name, u.phone, u.email, u.address, m.name, m.designantion, m.phone, m.email, m.image FROM kvves_units AS u JOIN kvves_members AS m ON m.unit_id = u.id WHERE name = '$committee'"
```

Comment: $kvvesDetails = $conn->prepare(
                            "SELECT u.id, u.name, u.phone, u.email, u.address, m.name, m.designantion, m.phone, m.email, m.image
                            FROM kvves_units AS u
                            JOIN kvves_members AS m ON m.unit_id = u.id WHERE `name` = $committee"
                            );


I'm using something like this can please edit this?

Comment: Looks OK. what is the error message you get? `WHERE name = $committee` must be `WHERE u.name = $committee`

Comment: am getting error like this

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'state' in 'where clause'' in D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\online-vyapari\business\kvvs.php:19 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\online-vyapari\business\kvvs.php(19): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\online-vyapari\business\kvvs.php on line 19

Comment: That can not be. You do not have any column `state` in your where statement. The error message must come from an other statement.

Comment: yes it is the same. 'state' is from GET method that means the variable $commitee returns 'state'

Comment: @SujithWayanad Now it is clear. I have updated my answer. You need ticks arround the value of `$commitee`

Comment: yea I have done that now everything is correct but now its returning empty array :(

Comment: Okey It was my mistake I got it Thanks Allot

Answer (score 1):

> Use this SQL

```
select kvves_units.*,kvves_members.* from kvves_units a join kvves_members b where a.name = b.name and a.name = '".$_GET['name']."'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$sql = "Select *from kvves_units as u INNER JOIN kvves_members as m where u.id = m.unit_id and u.name = '".$name."'";
```

You will get your solution.